# GEB: Disable implicit assertions in waitFor block

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, geb

I have a `waitFor{}` block with several lines inside:

```
waitFor(timeOutSeconds) {
    jobRow.clickUpdate()
    processDialog.waitIfShown()
    jobRow.statusCell.text() == status.value
}
```

According to [The Book of GEB](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#implicit-assertions-waiting):

> Any calls to refreshWaitFor() method have implicit assertions added to
>   each expression in the bloc passed to it just like for waitFor()
>   method calls.

The problem is that `processDialog.waitIfShown()` can return false, and this is actually okay if the progress bar was not displayed.

I need the only last row to be verified for groovy truth, so now I'm writing `processDialog.waitIfShown() || true` to skip this expression verification. This works but looks odd.

Is there any flag or option to turn off implicit assertions in waiting blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to disable implicit assertions for a specific `waitFor()` call then no, that's currently not supported out of the box. There is a number of workarounds, though:

- implicit assertions can be disabled globally if you remove `org.gebish:geb-implicit-assertions` artifact from the compile classpath - it's a transitive dependency of `geb-core` and excluding transitive dependencies is relatively easy in all major build systems
- implicit assertions are not applied on calls to void methods - if you wrap `processDialog.waitIfShown()` into a method having `void` as the return type then calls to that method will not be asserted
- implicit assertions are only applied to `waitFor()` calls if closure literals are passed to them - if you assign your condition closure to a variable and then pass that variable to the `waitFor()` call then no statements in that closure will be implicitly asserted

If you believe that the above options/workarounds are insufficient then please feel free to raise an issue in [the tracker](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at more recent versions of geb's [Page](https://gebish.org/manual/5.0/api/geb/Page.html), you'll see they've added a [getShouldVerifyAtImplicitly](https://gebish.org/manual/5.0/api/geb/Page.html#getShouldVerifyAtImplicitly()) method, which can be overridden on your implementation of a Page to return false. Since it's groovy, it's as easy as just defining...

```
boolean shouldVerifyAtImplicitly = false
```

...anywhere in your Page class.

Comment: verifyAt has nothing related to the question. The question is how to disable each-row-assertion inside the watiFor {} block, not in at checker.